# Help solving particular D.E

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm going through past exams for revision and couldn't get the same answer as the markscheme for this problem. QP http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20%289709%29/9709_w12_qp_33.pdf and MS http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Mathematics%20%289709%29/9709_w12_ms_33.pdf The question number is 4

$(x^2+4)dy/dx=6xy$ It is given that y=32 when x=0. Find an expression for y in terms of x.

This is what I have attempted so far:

(1) splitting both sides:
$$(1/y)dy=6x/(x^2+4)$$

(2) Integrating:
$$lny=3ln(x^2+4)+k$$

(3) solving for k:
$$k=ln(1/2)$$

(4) substituting back in and rearranging making y the subject
$$y=((x^2+4)^3)/2$$

However the answer is quoted as 
$$y=(x^2+4)/2$$

Comment: It's a typo. Your answer is correct.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for that.